# Is there a macro to split the contents of an Excel spreadsheet into separate spreadsheets?

Tags: microsoft-excel, macros, splitter

I know there are similar questions out there but I don't think they are quite the same.

I have an excel spreadsheet with the following headings-

`First name -- Surname -- Host Trust -- Contact details -- etc -- etc`

It is a large spreadsheet. I have to send an email every week to host trusts to inform them of who will be working with them and it is a nightmare dividing this up manually.

Is it possible to create a macro which will split this spreadsheet into several spreadsheets using the the data from the `Host Trust` column as the title of each spreadsheet?

Comment: Sure, use the macro recorded to see how it's done.  One easy way might be to filter your data on one specific Host Trust.  Then copy all of that.  Then paste it in the next sheet (although copy and paste isn't very efficient if you had to do hundreds of these).  Check the code the macro recorded made and make a few copies of it and edit them separately to see how to get it to work.

Comment: Do you have the code you are using that saves them to seperate workbooks?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not knowing what version of Excel you are using, I can not guarantee this will work. It does what you ask (I tested it), buy filtering on column C,  creates a tab for each unique record, then copies those rows to the new sheet. You will need to modify the code toward the top so it matches the range of your data.

**BEFORE YOU DO ANYTHING;** make a copy of your file as a backup.

If you are familiar with VBA, <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>F11</kbd> will open the VBA window, you can copy this code directly. Once saved, it will appear in the macro list for you to run.

To give credit where credit is due, I found this at [Excel Forum](http://www.excelforum.com/excel-programming/716639-moving-rows-of-data-to-another-sheet-with-vba.html).

```
Sub Copy_To_Worksheets()
'Note: This macro use the function LastRow
    Dim My_Range As Range
    Dim FieldNum As Long
    Dim CalcMode As Long
    Dim ViewMode As Long
    Dim ws2 As Worksheet
    Dim Lrow As Long
    Dim cell As Range
    Dim CCount As Long
    Dim WSNew As Worksheet
    Dim ErrNum As Long

    'Set filter range on ActiveSheet: A1 is the top left cell of your filter range
    'and the header of the first column, D is the last column in the filter range.
    'You can also add the sheet name to the code like this :
    'Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A1:D" & LastRow(Worksheets("Sheet1")))
    'No need that the sheet is active then when you run the macro when you use this.
    Set My_Range = Range("A1:O2000") '  & LastRow(ActiveSheet))
    My_Range.Parent.Select

    If ActiveWorkbook.ProtectStructure = True Or _
       My_Range.Parent.ProtectContents = True Then
        MsgBox "Sorry, not working when the workbook or worksheet is protected", _
               vbOKOnly, "Copy to new worksheet"
        Exit Sub
    End If

    'This example filters on the first column in the range(change the field if needed)
    'In this case the range starts in A so Field:=1 is column A, 2 = column B, ......
    FieldNum = 3 ' I changed this to 3 for column C

    'Turn off AutoFilter
    My_Range.Parent.AutoFilterMode = False

    'Change ScreenUpdating, Calculation, EnableEvents, ....
    With Application
        CalcMode = .Calculation
        .Calculation = xlCalculationManual
        .ScreenUpdating = False
        .EnableEvents = False
    End With
    ViewMode = ActiveWindow.View
    ActiveWindow.View = xlNormalView
    ActiveSheet.DisplayPageBreaks = False

    'Add a worksheet to copy the a unique list and add the CriteriaRange
    Set ws2 = Worksheets.Add

    With ws2
        'first we copy the Unique data from the filter field to ws2
        My_Range.Columns(FieldNum).AdvancedFilter _
                Action:=xlFilterCopy, _
                CopyToRange:=.Range("A1"), Unique:=True

        'loop through the unique list in ws2 and filter/copy to a new sheet
        Lrow = .Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
        For Each cell In .Range("A2:A" & Lrow)

            'Filter the range
            My_Range.AutoFilter Field:=FieldNum, Criteria1:="=" & _
             Replace(Replace(Replace(cell.Value, "~", "~~"), "*", "~*"), "?", "~?")

            'Check if there are no more then 8192 areas(limit of areas)
            CCount = 0
            On Error Resume Next
            CCount = My_Range.Columns(1).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible) _
                     .Areas(1).Cells.Count
            On Error GoTo 0
            If CCount = 0 Then
                MsgBox "There are more than 8192 areas for the value : " & cell.Value _
                     & vbNewLine & "It is not possible to copy the visible data." _
                     & vbNewLine & "Tip: Sort your data before you use this macro.", _
                       vbOKOnly, "Split in worksheets"
            Else
                'Add a new worksheet
                Set WSNew = Worksheets.Add(After:=Sheets(Sheets.Count))
                On Error Resume Next
                WSNew.Name = cell.Value
                If Err.Number > 0 Then
                    ErrNum = ErrNum + 1
                    WSNew.Name = "Error_" & Format(ErrNum, "0000")
                    Err.Clear
                End If
                On Error GoTo 0

                'Copy the visible data to the new worksheet
                My_Range.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Copy
                With WSNew.Range("A1")
                    ' Paste:=8 will copy the columnwidth in Excel 2000 and higher
                    ' Remove this line if you use Excel 97
                    .PasteSpecial Paste:=8
                    .PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
                    .PasteSpecial xlPasteFormats
                    Application.CutCopyMode = False
                    .Select
                End With
            End If

            'Show all data in the range
            My_Range.AutoFilter Field:=FieldNum

        Next cell

        'Delete the ws2 sheet
        On Error Resume Next
        Application.DisplayAlerts = False
        .Delete
        Application.DisplayAlerts = True
        On Error GoTo 0

    End With

    'Turn off AutoFilter
    My_Range.Parent.AutoFilterMode = False

    If ErrNum > 0 Then
        MsgBox "Rename every WorkSheet name that start with ""Error_"" manually" _
             & vbNewLine & "There are characters in the name that are not allowed" _
             & vbNewLine & "in a sheet name or the worksheet already exist."
    End If

    'Restore ScreenUpdating, Calculation, EnableEvents, ....
    My_Range.Parent.Select
    ActiveWindow.View = ViewMode
    With Application
        .ScreenUpdating = True
        .EnableEvents = True
        .Calculation = CalcMode
    End With

    MsgBox ("Copy Complete - - Remember to save your work.")


End Sub
```

Comment: HiThank you very much for your reply. in have used macros befor ebut took me about 3 weeks to eventually suss it out so i am a newby when it comes to this. Maybe my question should of been a buiit more precise. i am using excel 2010. the actually collum i need my data to be sorted by is located in Column F. Also do i have to set an output folder? or do i have to manually save each one? Apologies if i am being a bit 'Dim'!

Comment: You are welcome. In this code, you will need to change the column it uses to filter (line 31). Column F would be the sixth column, so change the 3 to a 6. 

When you asked about creating sheets, I thought you meant within the workbook. This code creates new sheets within the workbook for each unique field in the column sorted by. So if there are 13 Host Trusts, there will be 13 tabs. If you want it to create a *new file* for each one, that is different.

Comment: Please ignore my previous comment as i have found another macro to save to seperate work books. my only problkem now is qwhen i run this it splits half of my data fine but half of them are saved under the name Error 1, Error 2 etc. any ideas why?

Comment: Sorry. I do not know what the code you are using is doing to be able to know why it is doing that.

Comment: Apologies im probably confusing things now. i have used the code that you have provided above however when i run the macro 10 of the 20 records are saving under the name outputerror_0001. do you have any ideas why? Thanks for your help by the way

Comment: That is likely due to some tab naming error. The tabs only hold so many characters and do not support special characters. So if the Host Trust name is long, has symbols or punctuations in it, that might be why. If that is the case, you can just manually rename those tabs.

Comment: i think thats what it is. thank you for this youve been a big help and justy cut my workload down!!

Comment: Happy to help. Feel free to mark this answer with an approving check mark. Thanks.

Comment: HI Just wondering is it possible to set this up so it overwrites the worksheets it creates each time its run? i have set this up with another macro which then saves each worksheet created as a work book depending on what is in the 6th Column but if i run it and then run it agen rather than overwrite the previous sheets created it duplicates them and names them Error-1, Error-2 etc. Thanks for your help     Sean

Comment: You really should post it as a new question.